# How to derive relationship between two functions

Tags: functions, relations

I have two functions:

$f(x) = x^2 + 200$

$g(x) = (x + 8)^2$

[image]

I am interested in the relationship between the two functions in the region between the two minimums (from x = -8 to x = 0), which looks as follows:

[image]

How can I algebraically derive the equation of this relationship? I tried substitution but the results were not as expected (possibly due to real/imaginary numbers?).

Comment: What do you mean by relationship? What is the second graph?

Comment: See my answer for a plausible interpretation that yields the graph shown. :) Roughly: a function $t \mapsto u(t)$ with the property that $u(g(x)) =  f(x)$, where $f$ is the red function and $g$ the blue in the first graph.

Comment: Sorry, it's not very clear. The second graph shows the value of the first function on the horizontal axis and the value of the second function on the vertical axis, for the range x = -8 to x = 0

Comment: Then the second graph is wrong, because it is plotting $x$ from 0 to 8 instead of $x$ from 0 to -8.

Comment: No, almagest, you're wrong here. Look at the point in the second graph where the x-coord is about 250. The y-coord is then just about 0. In the upper graphs, there are two places where the blue graph hits 250 -- about  -8 and +8. And the red graphs at those two places have values 0 and perhaps 220. Clearly the lower graph comes from the "nearly 0" rather than "nearly 220" case.

Comment: @JohnHughes Yes, but he states just above the graph that that is not what he wants!

Comment: @almagest. The graph is what I want (it is just Excel's scatter with smooth lines). I was unable to determine the formula of the chart, but John has showed me how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your picture correctly, you want to know, given the value of the blue curve at some $x$-value between -8 and 0, the value of the corresponding red curve. So the input to your function will be a number $s$ between $200$ and perhaps $300$, and the output will be between about $0$ and $60$.

Here goes. Suppose we call the blue value $t$. Then the $x$-coordinate that produced that $t$ value is the one with 
$$
x^2 + 200 = t \\
x^2 = t - 200 \\
x = \pm\sqrt{t - 200}
$$
**At this point, you have to notice that in your graphs, $x$ is negative, while the usual definition of square-root is defiend to be the positive one. So you have to write**
$$
x = -\sqrt{t - 200}
$$

Now the point on the red curve corresponding to that $x$ value is 
$$
(x+8)^2 = (-\sqrt{t-200} + 8)^2
$$
So your function is 
$$
f(t) =  (-\sqrt{t-200} + 8)^2.
$$
You can expand that out algebraically, but it doesn't get a lot nicer:
$$
f(t) = (t-200) - 16 \sqrt{t-200} + 64 \\
= t - 16 \sqrt{t-200} - 136.
$$

Comment: I got the same formula as you, but when I plot it in Excel, I don't get the same curve as shown at the bottom of my question. Not sure if it's something to do with the root function and imaginary numbers.

Comment: @Caustix No, it is because your second graph is plotting $x\in(0,8)$ instead of $x\in(-8,0)$.

Comment: See my boldfaced edit to my answer. Apologies for my initially misleading answer.